# Use Javascript to change an elements href without an ID selector

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the logo link that is auto created from our database software.  The logo itself has an id, but the  anchor does not.

```
    <div id="storelogo" style="width:150px;height:55px;"> 
    <a style="border:0" href="//myshirtbuzz.com">
<img id="storelogoimage" src="logo.png" alt="MyShirtBuzz">
    </a>
            </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("storelogoimage").previousSibling.href="xyz.php";
     </script>
```

Comment: Your anchor isn't a sibling to `#storelogo`, it's a *child*.

Comment: Thanks Andre - using .firstElementChild instead on the "storelogo" worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logo is a child of the link, so your anchor is the parent.

Instead of `previousSibling`, use `parentNode`.

```
document.getElementById("storelogoimage").parentNode.href = 'xyz.php';
```

Comment: As an addition in case you are interested: [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode), [childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)